# Flutter EqualUnmodifiableListView error when i try to add json array inside the variable

Tags: json, flutter, dart, freezed

To use the output received from the server, which is in the following format:

```json
{
  "data": [{
    "id": 6,
    "config": "data",
  }]
}
```

And in Flutter, for converting this data, I have the following code using the Freezed library, and I don't have any issues:

```dart
@freezed
class ConfigsDto with _$ConfigsDto {
  const factory ConfigsDto({
    required List<Config> data,
  }) = _ConfigsDto;

  factory ConfigsDto.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$ConfigsDtoFromJson(json);
}

@freezed
class Config with _$Config {
  const factory Config({
    required String config,
  }) = _Config;

  factory Config.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$ConfigFromJson(json);
}
```

my model:

```dart
Future<ConfigsDto> getConfigs(String provider) async {
    try {
      return await _signupRepository.getConfigs(provider);
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      handleError(e);
      rethrow;
    }
}
```

and repository:

```dart
Future<ConfigsDto> getConfigs(String provider) {
  return _restApi.getConfigs(provider);
}
```

RestClient api implementation with `retrofit`:

```dart
@POST(DV.allConfigs)
Future<ConfigsDto> getConfigs(
  @Query('provider') String provider,
);
```

Now, to put this array inside a list and use it, I declared the following variable:

```dart
final List<ConfigsDto> _blogs = [];
```

And to add the array output to this variable, I wrote this code:

First, receive it from the server:

```dart
final res = await model.getConfigs(providerName);
```

result:

```json
ConfigsDto(data: [Config(id: 6, config: {
  "dns": {
    "hosts": {
      "domain:googleapis.cn": "googleapis.com"
    },
    "servers": [
      "1.1.1.1"
    ]
  },
  "inbounds": [
    {
      "listen": "127.0.0.1",
      "sniffing": {
        "destOverride": [
          "http"
        ],
        "enabled": true
      },
      "tag": "socks"
    },
    {
      "listen": "127.0.0.1"
    }
  ],
  "log": {
    "loglevel": "error"
  },
  "outbounds": [
    {
      "protocol": "vless",
      "streamSettings": {
      },
      "tag": "proxy"
    }
  ],
  "stats": {}
}, provider: 'test')])
```

Then, I want to put it inside the variable `_blogs`:

```dart
_blogs.clear();
_blogs.addAll(res.data as List<ConfigsDto>);
```

However, this line gives me the following error:

`type 'EqualUnmodifiableListView<Config>' is not a subtype of type 'List<ConfigsDto>' in type cast`

Comment: Can you check `res.runtimeType`

Comment: @Md.YeasinSheikh yes. its `_$ConfigsDtoImpl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an `EqualUnmodifiableListView<Config>` (which derives from `List<Config>`) and want a `List<ConfigsDto>`, but `Config` and `ConfigsDto` seem like unrelated types, and therefore `List<Config>` and `List<ConfigsDto>` are also unrelated.  Casts cannot convert between unrelated types.

You perhaps intend to perform a *transformation* instead:

```dart
_blogs.add(ConfigDto(data: res.data));
```

Comment: I updated post because i get this error: 
```Unhandled Exception: type '_$ConfigImpl' is not a subtype of type 'List<Config>' in type cast```

Comment: @DolDurma And where do you get that error?  There is no type cast in my suggested code.

Comment: in this line of code which you put it into your answer `_blogs.addAll(res.data.map((d) => ConfigsDto(data: d as dynamic)));` could you please check my question first? Shouldn't we use `fromJson` based on the  `ConfigDto` class?

Comment: @DolDurma Oops, I've updated my answer.  I didn't notice that the `ConfigsDto` constructor already takes a `List<Config>` instead of a single `Config` object.  Since `res.data` is already a `List<Config>`, I'm not sure why you aren't just calling `ConfigsDto(data: res.data)` directly.

Comment: you right, i found out what was problem, thanks so much